# Error invoking Method 'pushFile': Internal server error [500] on uploading with meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to upload a file to the server but I keep getting `Error invoking Method 'pushFile': Internal server error [500]` in the console. I am not exactly sure what is going on here. I am pretty much brand new to meteor and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
      Template.hello.events({
        'change .fileInput': function(event, template){
          event.preventDefault();
          // var theName = event.target.theName.value;
          console.log(theName);
          FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file){
            var fileObj = new FS.File(file);
            fileObj.itemtext = theName;
            Meteor.call("pushFile", fileObj);
          });
        }

      });


    }

    if(Meteor.isServer){
      Meteor.methods({
        'pushFile': function(fileObj){
        fileObj.userId = this.userId;
        Uploads.insert(fileObj, function(err){
            console.log(err);
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

the rest of the error is below:

```
I20151112-17:29:03.764(-5)? Exception while invoking method 'pushFile' Error: DataMan constructor received data that it doesn't support
I20151112-17:29:03.770(-5)?     at EventEmitter.FS.Collection.insert (packages/cfs_collection/packages/cfs_collection.js:269:1)
I20151112-17:29:03.770(-5)?     at [object Object].Meteor.methods.pushFile (uploadexample.js:39:21)
I20151112-17:29:03.769(-5)?     at new DataMan (packages/cfs_data-man/packages/cfs_data-man.js:75:1)
I20151112-17:29:03.770(-5)?     at setData (packages/cfs_file/packages/cfs_file.js:107:1)
I20151112-17:29:03.770(-5)?     at EventEmitter.fsFileAttachData [as attachData] (packages/cfs_file/packages/cfs_file.js:102:1)
I20151112-17:29:03.771(-5)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (livedata_server.js:1698:12)
I20151112-17:29:03.771(-5)?     at livedata_server.js:708:19
I20151112-17:29:03.771(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20151112-17:29:03.772(-5)?     at livedata_server.js:706:40
I20151112-17:29:03.772(-5)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
```

Comment: The rest of the error would be helpful. I assume it's complaining about the lack of definition for `currentUserId`. Perhaps you mean `this.userId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer here... [Meteor File Upload Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402765/meteor-file-upload-not-working)

> When you need to insert a file that's located on a client, always call myFSCollection.insert on the client. While you could define your own method, pass it the fsFile, and call myFSCollection.insert on the server, the difficulty is with getting the data from the client to the server. When you pass the fsFile to your method, only the file info is sent and not the data. By contrast, when you do the insert directly on the client, it automatically chunks the file's data after insert, and then queues it to be sent chunk by chunk to the server. And then there is the matter of recombining all those chunks on the server and stuffing the data back into the fsFile. So doing client-side inserts actually saves you all of this complex work, and that's why we recommend it.

Then to secure the insert, since it is coming from the client side, setup your allow / deny rules to decide who can insert what where. In your server folder, add a file (usually /server/allow/Uploads.js) Something like this...

```
Uploads.allow({
  insert: function (userId, doc) {
    // the user must be logged in, and whatever other constraints you want
    return (userId && otherCoolSecurityCheckFunction());
  },
  update: function (userId, doc, fields, modifier) {
    // can only change your own documents
    return doc.owner === userId;
  },
  remove: function (userId, doc) {
    // can only remove your own documents
    return doc.owner === userId;
  },
  fetch: ['owner']
});
```

See the allow docs for more information...

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow

Comment: Issues with that then is validating the user.

Comment: Updated to include server side user validation